# Need a simple regex

Tags: regex, pcre

Hi I need a Simple Regular expression in PCRE format to match something like

```
(Child OR Children) AND toys
```

Comment: I only know the OR operator... Dont know how to use the And operator.

Comment: There is no AND operator -- it's implicit.  Think of a regex as a long string of ANDs.

Comment: @MichaelM: You can use lookaheads and lookbehinds to get the effect of AND. See my answer for an example.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your reply.

Answer (score 3):

The following, or a slight derivative of the following, should work for you:

```
/(?:child|children) toys/i
```

Answer (score 1):

Question is not very clear about how word `toys` will appear after OR condition, but I think following should work for you:

```
/(?:^|\b)child(?:ren|)\b.*?(?<=\btoys\b)/i
```